# How to add values to array- Angular2

Tags: arrays, typescript

I made an array like this in angular2, and also I made a form to fill out a table and it works well. But my question is what is the best way to put some values in this array without filling the form, I want some content already in this array.

```
employeeList = new Array<{name:string, bio:string, job:string, salery:string, url:string}>();
```

Comment: Hi Aleksander, It helps if you can include your code in the question as text, as it makes it easier to copy and revise without re-typing

Comment: There is an option to edit the question.  As this is code, you can aslo format the code - select it and click on the {} icon

Comment: Yea I see now thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a class representing your structure:

```
export class User {
  name: string;
  bio: string;
  job: string;
  salary: string;
  url: string
  constructor(_name: string, _bio: string, _job: string, _salary: string, _url: string) {
    this.name = _name; this.bio = _bio; this.job = _job; this.salary = _salary; this.url = _url;
  }
}
```

or like this:

```
export class User {
  constructor(public name: string,
    public bio: string,
    public job: string,
    public salary: string,
    public url: string) {
  }
}
```

You array will look like this:

```
users: User[] = []; // if it's a class member
var users: User[] = []; // if it's a local variable
```

Add something to array:

```
this.users.push(
   new User("Bob", "", "Developer", "100", "github.com"); 
)
```

Comment: Please include in your constructor the initialization: this.name = _name;
this.bio = _bio; this.job = _job; this.salary = _salary; this.url = _url;