# How to push and update deep nested values in angular2 and maintain ui state

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

i have a deeply nested array as follow

```
mainarray[]:{
array1[]:{sub1_array1[]:{},sub2_array1:{}},
array2[]
... // and so on
}
```

since i am retriving main array on init how can i push sub2_array1 updated values?
but since on change view renders and ui state is changed including some active class components. so how can i maintain that? 
i read something about `pipes` and `changedetectorRef` but can't figure out how to use it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Something is very wrong with your array/object. And `tsc` complains about it. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/37824284/1267942

Very lively it's nothing to do do with `pipes` and `changedetectorRef`, you just need to declare your model correctly.

**Update**:
There are couple thing here:

1. Correct way of interacting between parent and child components https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#
2. Having common data model for multiple nested components:

Declare a class member in a parent component, like

```
model: Array<string> = [];
```

In the template pass it to a child component using two-way binding

```
<child-component [(modelInChild)]="model"></child-component>
```

In the child model variable should be declared as

```
@Input() modelInChild: Array<string> = [];
```

Then you can pass the variable further to child of child the same way.

Using this method you'll have common data `model` in the whole tree of components.
However, this method is not recommended: it's slow, it's hard to track value of a `model`, etc.

3. Component can use itself as a child. I haven't tried this approach yet, but [Angular2 Recursive Templates in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913643/angular2-recursive-templates-in-javascript) looks very promising.
4. For the `Collapsible` component check [Angular 2 Read More Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819312/angular-2-read-more-directive/37820535?noredirect=1#comment63112235_37820535)

Comment: hi thanks for the answer , actually when i update the low level model , i can not map and push it into higher model since its nested and can't map to exact dynamic location so basically i would need to call the whole higher level model again and map it again right? if yes its actually disturbing html resetting all "active" class component , is there any way to avoid this??

Comment: are you getting? i mean for eg. i have some list/collapsible components etc so the one which are open will be collapse again...

Comment: wow thats interesting ...dont know how its gonna work... i wil give it a try and will let you know, but i think angular2 should have something like compare data and change only which is necessary...why its not just simple with observable and BehaviorSubject ...